# Rails file_filed doesn't pass params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I have trouble with my image update

My form

```
  = form_for @user, :html => {class: "form form_profile"} do |user|
    = user.file_field :avatar
 .... other fields
  end
```

and controller `update` and `user_avatar_params` action

```
def update
 respond_to do |format|
       # binding.pry
      if params[:user][:avatar]

        if current_user.update(user_avatar_params)
          flash[:notice] = 'Updated
          format.html { render action: 'edit' }
          format.js { render 'success_edit', layout: false }
 ....
end




 def user_avatar_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
 end
```

my params from console

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "user"=>{"current_password"=>"", "password"=>""}, "action"=>"update", "controller"=>"users", "id"=>"2"}
```

i use `paperclip`

What wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `html: { multipart: true }` code like in the example below.

```
<%= form_for @user, url: users_path, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
<%= form.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
```